# Trouble with object injection in Spring.Net

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, spring.net

I have a issue with my Spring.Net configuration where its not injecting an object. I have a CommService to which an object named GeneralEmail is injected to. Here is the configuration:

```
<!-- GeneralMail Object -->    
<object id="GeneralMailObject" type="CommUtil.Email.GeneralEmail, CommUtil">
    <constructor-arg name="host" value="xxxxx.com"/>
    <constructor-arg name="port" value="25"/>
    <constructor-arg name="user" value="xxxx@xxxxx.com"/>
    <constructor-arg name="password" value="xxxxx"/>
    <constructor-arg name="template" value="xxxxx"/>  
</object>    
<!-- Communication Service -->  
<object id="CommServiceObject" type="TApp.Code.Services.CommService, TApp">
    <property name="emailService" ref="GeneralMailObject" />  
</object>
```

The communication service object is again injected to many other aspx pages & service. In one scenario, I need to call the commnucation service from an static WebMethod. I try doing:

```
CommService cso = new CommService();
```

But when i try to get the emailService object, its null! why didn't the spring inject the GeneralMail object into my cso object? What am I doing wrong and how do I access the object from spring container.

Thanks in advance for the suggestions and solutions.
Reagrds,
Abdel Olakara

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IApplicationContext ctx = ContextRegistry.GetContext();
CommService cso= (CommService)ctx.GetObject("CommServiceObject");
```